# Converting file content to string and store in sharepoint column

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a requirement to allow user to upload any file (pdf, doc, ect) to sharepoint and later on download the file as needed.  the upload and download tasks are implemented as asp.net web app.   Currently, I convert the file content (byte array) to base64 string and store in sharepoint.   For download, I get the content from sharepoint and do convert from base64 to string then I write this string to browser.  The result did not look like original file.  What is wrong?

Comment: Is not it out-of-the-box functionality of SharePoint? Note - your question does not meet SO quality bar as it is clearly coding question without any code shown. If you feel that re-implementing SP document libraries is required please show your code. Don't forget to check http://www.sscce.org on writing good sample code for questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it sounds like the problem is you are converting the Base64 data to a string. Since Base64 is a representation of binary data using only printable characters it works fine as a string, but interpreting binary data directly as a string can result in data corruption. It's like trying to edit an EXE file using Notepad.

You need to convert the Base64 back to a byte array and write that to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I went back and tried it out and now it works.